# IPython notebook install error

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to install IPython notebook on OS X 10.10.2.

After all dependencies have been added, this error occurs:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/tests.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jinja2._compat import text_type, string_types, integer_types
  ImportError: cannot import name integer_types
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How are you installing ipython?

If you have pip, are you using `pip install ipython[all]`?

I also recommend using virtualenv to start with a completely clean python2.7 install from scratch and see if you encounter the errors still. There may be some version compatibility conflicts on the system.

Alternative is you can install the Anaconda distribution which comes prepackaged with ipython and dependencies http://continuum.io/downloads